# Rhyming conventions of Early Modern English

Tags: pronunciation, terminology, early-modern-english, rhymes

I was reading the poem ["To His Coy Mistress"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_His_Coy_Mistress) by Andrew Marvell when something struck me as odd. Let me quote two passages:

> Thou by the Indian Ganges' side
>   Shouldst rubies find: I by the tide
>   Of Humber would complain. I would
>   Love you ten years before the Flood,

[...]

> But at my back I always hear
>   Time's wingèd chariot hurrying near;
>   And yonder all before us lie
>   Deserts of vast eternity.
>   Thy beauty shall no more be found,
>   Nor, in thy marble vault, shall sound
>   My echoing song: then worms shall try
>   That long preserved virginity,

Now, am I supposed to read *flood* as [fluːd], *eternity* as [ɪˌtɜː.nəˈtaɪ̯], and *virginity* as [vɜː(r)ˌdʒɪ.nəˈtaɪ̯]? Was one supposed to do so back in the 17th century? Or is this, and has always been, some sort of purely "visual" rhyme? The rest of the poem rhymes perfectly in contemporary English.

I guess I could sum it up in one question: What is the term for this type of rhyme?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it seems that in English poetry sometimes one goes off the metre or rhyme, and a few little variations are accepted (and even welcomed).

Comment: Before the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) English, the long i, as in *eye,* was pronounced /iː/ and short i was pronounced /i/ (or maybe /ɪ/). I am guessing that *eternity* ended with a short i. Anyway, this poem was written partway through the Great Vowel Shift, when according to Wikipedia, *eye* had the pronunciation something like /ɪi/ or /əɪ/; my guess is that *eternity* was pronounced with /ɪ/ or /i/. If this wasn't an exact rhyme then, it was at least a much closer near-rhyme than it is today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think *would* and *flood* are or were rhyming pairs in some dialects of English. This is not surprising, as /ʊ/ (as in *would*) and /ʌ/ (as in *flood*) are similar vowel sounds. I think in some dialects of modern British English, the two vowels are merged. The general term for words that *almost* rhyme is called *[slant rhyme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slant_rhyme)*. Words that are spelled like they might rhyme but are not are called *[eye rhymes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_rhyme)*.

As for the second passage, I think it is just a rhyming pattern of AABC DDBC.

Comment: I was going to say that I feel totally stupid for missing that pattern, but then I realized that I was fooled by the rest of the poem being written in rhyming couplets. Well played, Mr Marvell.

Comment: Actually, northern British dialects (like Liverpool) have failed to *split* /ʊ/ and /ʌ/, rather than succeeding to merge them. http://www.benjamins.com/cgi-bin/t_articles.cgi?bookid=EWW%2017:1&artid=388089513

Comment: *Try* and *virginity* did indeed have the same final vowel-sound.  That was one of the many changes in the Great Vowel Shift.  Both were once pronounced 'ee'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Words like FLOOD could still have a rounded vowel in some varieties of London English in the mid-to-late 17th century. There were varieties where the vowel in FLOOD shortened early in the 16th century and developed an unrounded vowel /ʌ/ by the middle of the 17th. But there were other speakers for whom matters were otherwise. The orthoepist Christopher Cooper (1687) is one of them. In describing his own preferred pronunciation, Cooper quite unambiguously has a vowel like /ʊ/ (the vowel of modern HOOD) in words like BLOOD and FLOOD.

If you want to hear me reading this poem aloud in a reconstruction of how Marvell's own English pronunciation may well have sounded, [click here](http://blogicarian.blogspot.com/2018/07/voices-of-early-english-marvell-to-his.html).