# Older pronunciations of the "-ity" suffix

Tags: pronunciation, suffixes, poetry, rhymes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rhyming conventions of Early Modern English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/rhyming-conventions-of-early-modern-english)

Andrew Marvell's poem [*To His Coy Mistress*](http://www.luminarium.org/sevenlit/marvell/coy.htm) from the mid-1600's follows an **AABBCCDD[...]** rhyming pattern. Therefore, it is jarring when we get to the couplets:

> And yonder all before us lie/
>   Deserts of vast eternity

and

> then worms shall try/ That long-preserved virginity

This implies that either:

- *"lie"* used to be pronounced as *"lee"* to rhyme with *"eternity"*, **and** *"try"* used to be pronounced *"tree"* to rhyme with *"virginity"*, or
- much more likely, both *"eternity"* and *"virginity"* used to rhyme with *"lie"*/ *"try"*.

Is this the case? If so, did this apply only to a few words like *"eternity"* and *"virginity"*, or to anything with the super-common *"-ity"* prefix, like *"formality"*, *"ability"*, or any of the words [listed here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ity)? And furthermore, if that is also the case, then when in the last 300 years did the change happen so quickly and so thoroughly that I cannot think of a single present-day *"-ity"* word that rhymes with *"try"*?

Comment: Or he just cheated and used a non-rhyme. Recall also William Blake's *The Tiger*: "What immortal hand or eye / Could frame thy fearful symmetry?", a similar cop-out.

Comment: Interesting. How do you know for sure that Blake's line is a cop-out, out of curiosity? It seems suspicious to me that this is a mis-rhyme on the same sound (_"eye"_, _"lie"_, and _"try"_ all rhyme, and _"eternity"_, _"virginity"_ and _"symmetry"_ all rhyme). This actually makes the change in pronunciation more likely to me, since it seems so unreasonable to suppose that all of these "cop-outs" all just happen to be on the exact same sound.

Comment: BTW thanks for asking the question; I'd like to know the answer too. Aside: Marvell's *[To His Coy Mistress](http://www.luminarium.org/sevenlit/marvell/coy.htm)* is indeed a great poem, but I also recommend A.D. Hope's *[His Coy Mistress to Mr. Marvell](http://wonderingminstrels.blogspot.com/2004/11/his-coy-mistress-to-mr-marvell-d-hope.html)* :-)

Comment: Wow, I'd never seen that poem before -- awesome find! Interestingly, it also has a mis-rhyme (_"move"_ and _"love"_) which I have very often found in Shakespeare. I suspect that one is a changed pronunciation too, although I'm assuming this second poem is recent enough for this to have been done "ironically" :)

Comment: If you look at the wikipedia article for the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), the vowel in *eye* was at that time pronounced /əi/ or /ɪi/, which, while still not the same vowel /i/ in *eternity*, is much closer, so might have been an acceptable near-rhyme. Since I don't know that much about this, and from the spelling, I'm guessing that the suffix *-y* started out as /i/ in 1400 (almost the same as the vowel /i:/ used in *eye* then), I'm not making this an answer.