# In what parts of the world do "again" and "rain" rhyme?

Tags: rhymes

I sometimes read rhyming poetry where  "again" and "rain" are clearly meant to rhyme. However in my accent they don't rhyme at all.   I am now wondering in which accents they do rhyme.

Comment: Perhaps in some regions of Great Britain.  I've definitely heard it before in media, and it's no surprise at all.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou Do you know where in Great Britain? It doesn't rhyme in my British friends' accents. Also, the fact that it appears in published poetry suggests to me that it must be in a common accent.

Comment: I dunno.  Scotland?

Comment: It rhymes everywhere in the Anglosphere _in poetry_. In normal speech, _again_ is /əˈɡen/ while _rain_ is /reɪn/ in most dialects I can think of—but in exaggerated, quaint, archaic, or poetic speech/writing, _again_ can frequently be /əˈɡeɪn/ if needed.

Comment: Possibly related: *[What do you call “rhymes” which are spelt but not sounded the same way?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233111)*, *[Was the pronunciation of “symmetry” different in the past?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216345)*, *[Rhyme in Elizabethan sonnets](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73645)*, and *[Rhyming conventions of Early Modern English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1975)*.

Comment: In *My Fair Lady*, I believe.

Comment: I've always thought that *again* has two pronunciations, much like *either*. Living in Canada, I frequently hear both.

Comment: Poetry often uses near-rhymes. How can you be sure they are meant to be true rhymes?

Comment: The rain again falls mainly in Britain.

Comment: @SvenYargs I am not sure of the point you are making :) The related sentence I know is "The rain in Spain falls mainly in the plain.".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Do you have any evidence to back up the claim "It rhymes everywhere in the Anglosphere in poetry."   My suspicion is that in fact you could draw a pronunciation map of Britain and it would show that in some parts it rhymes and in others it doesn't. I just don't know where exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I pronounce to rhyme mostly. Brought up in the East Midlands. But I'm not sure but that context and mood doesn't affect the vowel quantity. I think I might be different in "Again, again, the bloody rain" versus "Oh no, he did it again".

Answer (score 1):

OED has this pronunciation:  Brit.  /əˈɡɛn/ , /əˈɡeɪn/ , U.S. /əˈɡɛn/

Not mentioning "quaint" or "archaic" at all.

Comment: Thank you. I know it is possible but I was hoping for some sort of pronunciation map.